# images not loading in Internet Explorer. why?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser, imagesource

ive been finally polishing off a website i was building but to my dismay i recently checked the website in Internet Explorer and found the images weren't loading fully.. you can see can the borders for the image but nothing loads in between. i thought it might something i altered on wordpress, but the main page has images from from non wordpress html files and they don't load either.. everything works fine on every other browser except Internet Explorer.. any ideas why? probably a simple fix
here's the website.. . all the code and css is viewable there, if you want my wordpress code let me know
maybe the code just needs to rearranged to make window browsers happy?
any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for the shop.html, it looks like you are specifying the height of the images, but not the width. Opera, and Firefox are ignoring the width="" and using the default width, but IE is setting it to width="1." I don't know how to change this in Wordpress but if you remove the width="" or add a value it will show correct.

You can see this if you r-click the image line in IE and select properties: it shows as 1X290px.

```
img src="images/shop/julianduron.jpg" width="" height="290"
```

hope this helps